In command prompt, how to toggle a behavior on and off? E.g. a toggle that makes each command print its start and end time after the command completes
In Windows 11, I often have several command prompts open and I sometimes forget which command prompt was the last one I ran a command in (e.g. when I take a break or come back the next day).
It would really help if I could toggle a command to print the

the system time that the command was ran at
the system time that the command completed execution
after the command completes.


I know how to do this manually for a command foo:
set startDate=%date% & set startTime=%time% & foo & echo start = %startDate% %startTime% & echo compl = %date% %time%

but that's too verbose. Ideally, there'd be a way to toggle this time printing behavior on and off -- either on and off for a specific command or for the all commands.
